# Django form This field is required error after request.POST

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms, django-views

I have multiple duplicate forms(model forms) which I use to to generate my layout for creating devices, with added prefix to each form. (can't use formsets for other reasons)

form:

```
class CreateModbusForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ModbusDevice
        fields = ['ixModbusDevice', 'sModbusName','iPort', 'iSlave', 'sIP']
        widgets = {
                'sModbusName': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Device Name','class': 'form-control','data-form': '0',}),
                'iPort': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Port','class': 'form-control','data-form': '0',}),
                'iSlave': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Slave id','class': 'form-control','data-form': '0',}),
                'sIP': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Modbus IP address','class': 'form-control','data-form': '0',})
            }

view:

modbus_qset = ModbusDevice.objects.all()
if modbus_qset:
    for device in modbus_qset:
        modbus_form = CreateModbusForm(instance=device, prefix="modbus-id_" + str(device.pk))
```

[image]

the problem I'm running into is when I post the data back to update(ajax post), my form always has the `This field is required` error.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    my_dic = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(request.POST['form']))

    modbus_device = CreateModbusForm(my_dic, prefix='modbus-id_2')#hard coded for testing
```

Doesn't matter what I do my form won't  pass the `is_valid()` because of this error but I don't know why it's giving me this if I'm passing the post data

(I have to convert my `request.POST['form']` since it's serialized as json from an ajax call and ends up being unicode instead of a QueryDict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I realized that my `name` and `id`'s in my html had a wrong format. django would generate an id like `id_modbus-id_2-iPort`, but my problem was that my id had an underscore instead of a hyphen. so my id's were `id_modbus-id_2_iPort` and django didn't recognize it